# How do I convert int(input) into a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

From this comment:

> I mean if the user inputs "00000000" which is an integer, it will become [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

I believe all you want is:

```
a = list(map(int, input("enter first byte: ")))
b = list(map(int, input("enter second byte: ")))
```

edit: python3 compatibility changes thanks to Tadhg McDonald-Jensen

edit2: Since you can't use ^ on lists, you could instead use this code:

```
a = input("enter first byte: ")
b = input("enter second byte: ")

def half_adder(a, b):
    S = ""
    c = ""
    for i in range(8):
        S += str(int(a[i]) ^ int(b[i]))
        c += str(int(a[i]) & int(b[i]))
    return (S,c)

def full_adder(a, b, c):
    (s1, c1) = half_adder(a, b)
    (s2, c2) = half_adder(s1, c)
    return (s2, (c1 or c2))

print(full_adder(a, b, "00000000"))
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "converting an int to a list"? You may construct a list containing the int by `[a]`, but that's not a conversion.

Comment: I mean if the user inputs "00000000" which is an integer, it will become [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

Comment: and what if they enter `147`? would the list contain `[1,4,7]`?

Comment: since you convert as integer, there's no way entering "0000" creates [0,0,0,0].

Comment: yes , if they enter 147 the list contain [1,4,7] and if I called a function to do the 3rd position of that list it would start from the int [7] in [1,4,7]

Comment: `"00000000"` is a `str` not an `int`. You may then simply do `[int(el) for el in a]`, where `a` is your input, i.e. `a = input('...')`.

Comment: btw `(c1 or c2)` is the logical `or`, the bitwise or is `(c1 | c2)`

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen yes its the logical bitwise operator for the OR_GATE, thanks! the reason why I put (int(input is because the bitwise operators don't work with strings ):

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre he reason why I put (int(input is because the bitwise operators don't work with strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you need:

```
>>> x=42
>>> list(map(int, "{:08b}".format(x)))
[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
```

the format string `"{:08b}"` means: convert the integer to a string in binary, at least 8 digits, 0-filled.

Comment: Apparently map returns an iterable in python3.

Comment: that's why I don't use `map` anymore. I use list comprehensions instead.

Comment: I didn't know that. +1

Comment: not sure _at all_ it answers the unclear question, though.

Comment: @EmanuelePaolini Basically I'm using bitwise operators to simulate a full adder, and I need to loop def full_adder 8 times. but I can't do that without having my users input be a list first.

Comment: This is a list-comprehension version of this answer: `[int(i) for i in "{:08b}".format(x)]`

Answer (score 0):

From this comment:

> I mean if the user inputs "00000000" which is an integer, it will become [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

I believe all you want is:

```
a = list(map(int, input("enter first byte: ")))
b = list(map(int, input("enter second byte: ")))
```

edit: python3 compatibility changes thanks to Tadhg McDonald-Jensen

edit2: Since you can't use ^ on lists, you could instead use this code:

```
a = input("enter first byte: ")
b = input("enter second byte: ")

def half_adder(a, b):
    S = ""
    c = ""
    for i in range(8):
        S += str(int(a[i]) ^ int(b[i]))
        c += str(int(a[i]) & int(b[i]))
    return (S,c)

def full_adder(a, b, c):
    (s1, c1) = half_adder(a, b)
    (s2, c2) = half_adder(s1, c)
    return (s2, (c1 or c2))

print(full_adder(a, b, "00000000"))
```

Comment: to be compatible with python3 you'd need to either wrap your `map` call in a call to `list` or use list comprehension.

Comment: I get     S = a ^ b # ^ is the xor bitwise operator
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ^: 'list' and 'list'

Comment: @vxguhe see my edit... even if it wasn't your original question

Comment: @AndrewDean IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level. and I tried to align it all but can't seem to make it go away

Comment: @vxguhe try again now? I'm sure you can manually fix an indentation error though...

Comment: @AndrewDean TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable o.O

Comment: @vxguhe Well since your `half_adder()` function takes strings of length 8 now, you need to pass it `"00000000"` instead of `0`. I've updated this in the code above too, so you can copy paste it. Also you should try learn more about reading backtraces and googling errors, it would save you having to come ask other people, and it'll help you learn too, but maybe that's not your intention.

Comment: @AndrewDean I've been googling for a while and couldn't find a way to solve it, I've been thrown in this deep end of python and when trying to do something  googling and not having right guidance not help much. I appreciate your help tons, I do want to learn code.

Comment: @vxguhe bye the way, if you want it to work for any length of `a` and `b` you should change `for i in range(8):` to `for i in range(len(a)):`